# Calculate the last Friday with at least two business days left

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am trying to write a little function using a series of functions from the `timeDate` package to figure out what the last Friday of every month with *at least* two business days left.

Getting the fourth Friday is easy:

```
> timeNthNdayInMonth("2014-11-01",nday=5,nth=4)
GMT
[1] [2014-11-28]
```

However, in the case of November, I would want it to return `2014-11-21` because there are no other business days left in November after the 28th. I guess what I need is some sort of `ifelse` to determine what the argument `nth` should equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly simple once you calculate the last day of the month as it is then a simple subtraction of 4 days if a Tuesday increasing by one until you get to 10 days if a Monday. You can calculate this with modular arithmetic.

```
freakyFriday <- function(year,month){
    lastDay <- as.Date(paste(year+ifelse(month==12,1,0),(month%%12)+1,1,sep="-"))-1
    dayNo <- as.integer(strftime(lastDay,"%w"))
    lastDay - ((dayNo-2)%%7+4)
}

freakyFriday(2014,7)
[1] "2014-07-25"
freakyFriday(2014,11)
[1] "2014-11-21"
freakyFriday(2014,1:12)
 [1] "2014-01-24" "2014-02-21" "2014-03-21" "2014-04-25" "2014-05-23"
 [6] "2014-06-20" "2014-07-25" "2014-08-22" "2014-09-26" "2014-10-24"
[11] "2014-11-21" "2014-12-26"
```

Comment: haha "freakyFriday". thanks for the solution, I just came up with something similar a few minutes ago. I pick an initial date (4th Friday), use the timeLastDayInMonth function, take a difftime, subtract two, and if the numeric value is less than 2, I need to grab the third Friday. This works because a 5th Friday will NEVER qualify.